# Java MouseEvent and Run Loop

Tags: java, loops

I was coding the main loop for a game and had a problem with this:

I have a class implementing a `MouseListener`, I add an instance of this class to my main class Game,
moreover I call `addMouseListener` on the window contained in my game class

My game class has a `boolean` called Running to stop the main loop,
I try to put this `boolean` to false when the `MouseListener` receive the event `MousePressed`,
on its side the instance of `MouseListener` put a `boolean` pressed to true when the mouse is pressed

The problem is that if I leave my loop empty with nothing else than checking if the mouse has been pressed by looking the variable pressed from the `MouseListener`, it doesn't stop looping;

I did a lot of loop like this but my loop was never empty so it was detected,
for example if I add print or a repaint in the loop the `MouseListener` and the Game instance seems to communicate, but not in the case of the nearly empty loop

Also it does print `mousePressed` and sets `pressed` to `true` (seen in debug mode)
but the call to `isPressed` does not return `true`.

**GAME CLASS**

```
public class Game  implements Runnable{

    private static Game game = null;

    private WindowManager wm;
    private ML ml;
    private KL kl;


    public boolean isRunning;

    private State currentState;

    private Game(){
        this.wm = new WindowManager();
        this.ml = new ML();
        this.kl = new KL();

        wm.addKeyListener(kl);
        wm.addMouseMotionListener(ml);
        wm.addMouseListener(ml);

        isRunning = true;

        changeState(C.MENU);
    }

    public static Game getGame(){
        if(game == null){
            game =   new Game();
        }
        return game;
    }

    public void changeState(int code){
        switch(code){
            case C.MENU : currentState = new MenuState(kl, ml);
            break;

            case C.GAME : currentState = new GameState(kl ,ml);
            break;

            case C.CLOSE: isRunning = false;
            break;

            default : break;
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        double lastFrameTime = 0.0;
        double dt = 0.0;

        while(isRunning){
            dt = Time.getTime() - lastFrameTime;
            lastFrameTime+= dt;


            if(ml.isPressed()){ //here not detected
                isRunning = false; 
            }
        }

        wm.closeWindow();
    }
}
```

**MOUSE LISTENER IMPLEMENTATION**

```
public class ML extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener {
    private double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
    private boolean pressed = false;

    public boolean isPressed() {
        return pressed;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        pressed = true;
        if(pressed)
            System.out.println("presed");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        pressed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        this.x = e.getX();
        this.y = e.getY();
    }

    public double getX(){
        return this.x;
    }

    public double getY(){
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

**THE WINDOW CLASS**

```
public class WindowManager extends JFrame {

    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;

    public WindowManager(){
        this.setSize(C.SCREEN_WIDTH, C.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle(C.TITLE);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setVisible(true);

        this.createBufferStrategy(2);
        this.bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        this.g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    }

    public void closeWindow(){
        if(g != null){
            g.dispose();
            System.out.println("Window Manager : Graphics g released");
        }
        if(bs != null){
            bs.dispose();
            System.out.println("Window Manager : BufferStrategy(2) bs released");
        }
        this.dispose();
        System.out.println("Window Manager : Window wm released -> close");
    }

    public void updateScreen(){
        if(!bs.contentsLost()){
            bs.show();
        }
    }

    public Graphics getG(){
        return this.g;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are new, you might not know that when posting code, you can enclose it with the {} tag. Otherwise, lines which don't have four spaces at the start will not appear as code. I'm afraid I don't know why the loop is not reading the variable from the ML class. Eventually you will do something to regulate the frame rate, though, yes?  Maybe there are folks at jvm-gaming.org who could answer this. Questions like these used to come up a lot there.

Comment: yes i'm new ty, and yes i will regulate the frame rate with a sleep when i'll figure why it does not read the variable, by the way the code works with a Thread.sleep, even for sleep(0)

Comment: Is the runnable executing on Swing's EDT (Event Dispatch Thread)? I recall that there are certain conditions where the manager of the EDT decides to pass over elements on the queue. Maybe something like that is happening, especially since the code in the while loop has no side effects outside of the run method.

Comment: No it is executed  on another thread, i think it's the origin of the problem but i have no idea  how "linking" the game thread with the event dispatch one

Comment: if i step over the loop(after suspending the game thread with a breakpoint) on debug mod, after pressed mouse on the window, the variable running is put to false, but it does not work on normal execution